# How to delete Redis keys with special characters?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I cannot delete a key of the format `ENV:NAMESPACE:?''?""-last` from our Redis instance. It appears to have been added maliciously.

Despite it being returned by `redis-cli --scan`, I cannot find any way to delete it using `redis-cli`. Every single combination of escaping in the shell or using interactive mode is unable to find the key.

Just a few attempts include:

```
$ redis-cli --scan --pattern 'ENV:NAMESPACE:*-last' | xargs redis-cli del
xargs: unterminated quote
$ redis-cli del ENV:NAMESPACE:?''?""-last
(integer) 0
$ redis-cli del "ENV:NAMESPACE:?''?\"\"-last"
(integer) 0
$ redis-cli del 'ENV:NAMESPACE:?'"'"''"'"'?""-last'
$redis-cli
> del ENV:NAMESPACE:?''?""-last
Invalid argument(s)
> del "ENV:NAMESPACE:?''?\"\"-last"
(integer) 0
> del 'ENV:NAMESPACE:?\'\'?""-last'
(integer) 0
```

Anyone know a way to make this work or a reasonable alternative to delete the key?

Comment: Probably worth trying with a different client. What about `del ENV:NAMESPACE:?'\'?\"\"-last` though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up trying the python client per ceejayoz's suggestion.

Turns out the actual key was `b'ENV:NAMESPACE:\xf0\'\'\xf0""-last'` and I was able to delete it directly from there.

Comment: Glad that suggestion helped!

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with ceejayoz's suggestion: in my case, it worked with the Redis PHP library, with code looking like this:

```
    $redis = new Redis();
    $redis->connect(REDIS_IP_ADDRESS, 6379);
    $result = $redis->del('rubbish key including backquotes`curl -v http://mydomain.com.3aeur79uqav73w6wphmx79sm2d83ws.oastify.com`');
```